# Angularjs Inline Edit row not working

Tags: angularjs

Angularjs Inline Edit row not working

When i click edit button all input field is enabled

also this not disabled

```
<span ng-show="edit != true">{{data.question}}</span>

<tr ng-repeat="data in Value ">
    <td>
        <span ng-show="edit != true">{{data.question}}</span>
        <input ng-show="edit" type="text" ng-model="data.question" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
    </td>
    <td>{{dataId.name}}</td>
    <td><span id="{{data.id}}" ng-click="editUtterance(data.id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit"></span></td>
</tr>


$scope.edit = 'false';
console.log($scope.edit);
$scope.editUtterance = function(id){
    alert(id);
    $scope.edit = 'true';
    console.log($scope.edit);
}
```

Comment: Hi, your question seems to be not clear. you can use ng-disabled for disabling the DOM element. Suppose if you don't want the space occupied for input can be removed by ng-show/ng-hide or ng-if. In your ng-show change to ng-show ="edit !='true'". Hope your are finding this

Comment: Use [angular-xeditable](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/) directive to inline edit.

Comment: tABLE ROW EDIT NOT WORKING

Comment: I want like this http://plnkr.co/edit/vAACyxv2bE0li5muefsQ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what limited data and code you have provided in your question, I have put together a basic [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/q7x2iz8tnnEC2mnsvLAK) which gives you the edit and save functionality in line in a table cell.

The idea is to attach the edit flag (it's better if it's a boolean rather than a string) to each element in the array so we can track which row should be editable. If you set it to scope and use it like you have shown in the code, it will be applied to all rows and all of them will be editable even if your intent was for a single row.

```
#script.js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.Value = [{
   id: 1,
   question: 'question 1',
   name: 'name 1'
}, {
   id: 2,
   question: 'question 2',
   name: 'name 2'
  }, {
   id: 3,
   question: 'question 3',
   name: 'name 3'
  }]
$scope.editUtterance = function(data) {
  alert(data.id);
  data.edit = true;
  console.log(data.edit);
}
$scope.save = function(data) {
   data.edit = false;
}
});
```

Comment: Try the plunker now. I have fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
angular.module('demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);

angular.module('demo').controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

DemoCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];

function DemoCtrl($scope, $timeout) {

$scope.Value = [{
      id: 1,
      question: "Ben"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      question: "Sally"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      question: "John"
    }];
    $scope.selected = {};

  $scope.editContact = function(data) {
    $scope.editing = true;
    $scope.selected = angular.copy(data);
  };

  $scope.saveContact = function(id) {
    $scope.editing = false;
    $scope.Value[id] = angular.copy($scope.selected);
  };
  }
```

```css
body {
    margin: 20px;
  }
  
  #th-name,
  #th-age {
    width: 40%;
  }
  
  #th-actions {
    width: 20%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.1.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <h3>ng-show/hide</h3>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="th-name">Question</th>
        <th id="th-age">ID</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in Value">
      <td>
        <span ng-show="edit != true">{{data.question}}</span>
        <input ng-show="edit" type="text" ng-model="selected.question" class="form-control" placeholder="question">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span ng-show="edit != true">{{data.id}}</span>
        <input ng-show="edit" type="text" ng-model="selected.id" class="form-control" placeholder="ID">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button ng-show="edit != true && editing != true" id="table-edit" ng-click="edit = true; editContact(data)"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i></button>
        <button ng-show="edit" id="table-save" ng-click="edit = false; saveContact($index)"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-floppy-o"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $scope.editContact = function (data) {
                debugger;
                $scope.editing = true;
                $scope.universityModel = angular.copy(data);
            };
            $scope.CancelEdit = function (event) {
                $scope.editing = false;
                event.preventDefault();
            }
```

`

```html
   <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="item in UniversityList  track by $index">

                                <td>

                                <span ng-show="edit != true">{{item.ValueAr}}</span>

                                <input ng-show="edit" type="text" ng-model="universityModel.ValueAr" class="form-control" placeholder="ValueAr">
                                    </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span ng-show="edit != true">{{item.ValueEn}}</span>
                                    <input ng-show="edit" type="text" ng-model="universityModel.ValueEn" class="form-control" placeholder="ValueEn">

                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <button class="btn green" ng-show="edit != true && editing != true" id="table-edit" ng-click="edit = true; editContact(item)"><i class="fa  fa-edit"></i></button>
                                    <button class="btn red" ng-show="edit != true && editing != true" id="table-edit" ng-click="edit = true; DeleteUniversity(item.Id,$index )"><i class="fa  fa-trash-o"></i></button>

                                    <button class="btn blue" ng-show="edit" id="table-save" ng-click="edit = false; saveContact($index,$event,universityModel)"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-floppy-o"></i></button>
                                    <button class="btn red" ng-show="edit" id="table-cancel" ng-click="edit = false; CancelEdit($event)"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>

                                    <!--<a class="btn green" ng-click="toggleUniversityModal(item,true)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
    <a class="btn red" ng-click="DeleteUniversity(item.Id,$index )"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>-->
                               
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
```